# Regex for validation on first n character

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with the regular expression for the following requirement.

- Input should be at least 1 character and can contain maximum of 79 characters.
- Only alphabets and whitespace `([a-zA-Z ]{1,79})`
- If the length exceeds `24` characters, then it should contain at least one whitespace.

Comment: `^(?=.{1,79}$)(?:(?=.{25})(?=\S*\s)[a-zA-Z ]+|[a-zA-Z ]+)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you also want to avoid leading/trailing/double spaces, you could try:

```
^(?!\S{25,}$|.{80})[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*$
```

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?!` - Open negative lookahead:

  - `\S{25,}$` - Any 25 (or more) non-whitespace characters up to the end.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `.{80}` - Any 80 characters other than newline.
  - `)` - Close negative lookahead.
- `[a-z]+` - 1+ alphabets.
- `(?:` - Open non-capturing group:

  - `[a-z]+` - A literal space followed by 1+ alphabets.
  - `)*` - Close non-capturing group and match it 0+ times.
- `$` - End line anchor.

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sr3N1g/1).

---

**Note:** If you don't mind about spaces, then you can use `^(?!\S{25,}$|.{80})[a-z ]+$` essentially also allowing for input like        .

Answer (score 3):

You might use

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,24}|(?=.{1,79}$)[a-zA-Z]* [a-zA-Z ]*)$
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[a-zA-Z]{1,24}` Match 1-24 times a char a-zA-Z
  - `|` Or
  - `(?=.{1,79}$)` Positive lookahead to assert 1-79 chars
  - `[a-zA-Z]* [a-zA-Z ]*` Match optional chars a-zA-Z followed by a space and optional chars a-zA-Z and a space
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DZsm5P/1)